# Getting most likely documents of the query using phonetic filter in solr

Tags: solr, n-gram, search-suggestion, error-correction, phonetics

I am using **solr** for **spell checking/ query correction**. I have added **solr.PhoneticFilterFactory** and **solr.NGramFilterFactory** in fieldType to perform **spell checking**.
It is **working fine** but here the **problem** is that I am **getting number of documents** of the query. I need only **most likely words/documents** or in similar words, we can say that **nearer words/documents** to the **query**.

Snippet of **schema.xml** :

```
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">         
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="1000" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Example** :
For a **query** "**piece**". I am getting around **780 NumFound**(Number of documents). I need to **reduce** this counts but with **most likely number of documents**.

Comment: Any reason why you're using _both_ ngram and phonetic? That will result in almost every document matching every (shortish) query. You might also want to test a different phonetic encoder.

Comment: `@ MatsLindh:` I tried with **different phonetic encoder** but I think **DoubleMetaphone encoder** is good among all. There is any something relevant to **threshold** by which I can get only the **most popular terms/documents** for the query.

Comment: @iNikkz can you share which all terms get matched with `piece`?

Comment: @sidgate: I am getting words like 'preace, place, peace, etc. there are 780 words.

Comment: @iNikkz - Were you able to get a solution here??