# EdgeNGramFilterFactory is not working fine in solr

Tags: solr, indexing, n-gram, search-suggestion

I am trying **solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory** in **solr** which is **explained** [here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Wildcard-searching-with-ngrams)
I have added `<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" />` in the **index analayzer** in the **fieldType** of **schema.xml**. 
As I know, **solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory** creates tokens such as

```
whether - wh, whe, whet, wheth, whethe, whether.
```

So, when I am **searching** for the query - **whether**, it gives **all documents** that contains the **tokens of the whether word**

```
"suggestion":["wether","ether","heather","walther" "weather","wheeler", "fletcher", "shepherd","together","whenever","wherever","another","blather","bother","brother","chothe","eiher","either","farther","father""feather","further","gather","goethe","günther" "higher","hucher","leather","mother","neither","nyheter", "other","rather","whence",      "where""shepherds","weathered","altogether","breathed","brothers","feathers","hitherto","northern","preacher","southern","withered"]
```

I need to only the **relevant documents** such as for **whether** word, I need `weather, wether, ether, heather` **not** the **unnecessary document** like `brother, shepherd etc`.

**schema.xml**:

```
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>        
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**solrconfig.xml :**

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">term</str>
     <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.jaspell.JaspellLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
      </lst> 
    </searchComponent>

   <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">term</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">500</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **First thing** :

**solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory** doesn't work popular on the **suggestions** we get in the suggestion block. **Suggestions** are coming by default using `class="solr.SpellCheckComponent"` **solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory** works on the **response /result** that comes from the **query** which we ask.

- **Second :**

  MaxResultForSuggest = value. where value may be 10 (integer)

If the **results/response** of the **query** are coming **more** than set **value of MaxResultForSuggest** then it gives `CorrectlySpelled = true` and **doesn't** give suggestions on the query while if the results/response of the query are coming less than set value of **MaxResultForSuggest** then it gives `CorrectlySpelled = false` and **gives suggestions** on the query.

```
         <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">10</str>
```

- **Third :**

You can set the **limit** to **display suggestion** using **spellcheck.alternativeTermCount**.

```
        <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">20</str>
```

- **Fourth :**

**OnlyMorePopular= true** :- Works **better** in **/suggest** because it always gives suggestions on the word whether it may be correctly spelled or wrong.

**OnlyMorePopular= true** :- Works **worse** in **/spell** because it **doesn't** gives suggestions on the **correct** word. In my case, It is working like this and I need suggestion on the correctly spelled word also. So, I **removed** **OnlyMorePopular** property and **default value** of **OnlyMorePopular** is **false**.

```
  <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
```

Build **good suggestion** on both **correctly spelled word** as well as **incorrect word**.

**Schema.xml :**

```
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Solrconfig.xml** :

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">term</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>      
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">2</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">term</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">30</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the minGramSize to a larger value, eg. 4 or 5 in order to reduce the number of irrelevant matches. Also, have a look at the documentation for more details https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Comment: Thanks for your Response. I know by maximizing the minGramSize will reduce the numbers but it will affect on the 2,3 characters of the query.

Comment: Yes, I think I see what you mean. But, in: "I need weather, wether, ether, heather" the last two are not valid, as EdgeNGram starts from the beginning of the token.

What other filters are you using? Is there any chance that you are using solr.NGramFilterFactory instead of solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory?

Comment: I am not using solr.NGramFilterFactory. But even the suggestion are coming like brother, heather etc. which are not started from the beginning of the token(EdgeNGram). I have pasted my schema.xml and solrconfig.xml. Will you check please that why I am getting those suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: **@spyk:** Will you please help to solve this problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484326/getting-most-likely-documents-of-the-query-using-phonetic-filter-in-solr?rq=1]. It is also similar to this question.

Comment: First, please keep the same order on the query and index analyzers in your fieldType. You are trying to use the ngram field to do spellchecking, so I believe you are spellchecking the ngrams. Can you try removing the edge ngram filter, reindex, and check the results again?

Comment: `@spyk:` Now, I have tried with **ngram filter**. It is giving all the **terms** which have **grams(tokens)** of the query. Now, what I want is that **minimum edit distance** will  come first in the output. I have **updated** the **schema.xml**. See the question again please. Results are coming nice but not as what I expect..

Comment: I meant completely removing any ngram filter from the field type and let the spellchecker work on the plain token.

Comment: If I understand correctly your use case, you need suggestions even if the input terms are spelled correctly? Can you try adding <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">10</str> to your "/suggest" requestHandler (or add &spellcheck.alternativeTermCount=10 param to your url)  - no ngram filters again.

Comment: **@ spyk:** Thanks for your great help and response.. I got the answer. I will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

As I see in your schema.xml file, you are using the NGramFilterFactory instead of the **Edge**NGramFilterFactory. This means that your are not creating tokens like you described:

> whether - wh, whe, whet, wheth, whethe, whether.

With the NGramFilterFactory you use the tokens will look like this:

> whether - wh, whe, whet, wheth, whethe, whether, he, het, heth, hethe, hether, et, eth, ethe, ether, th, the, ther, ...

Depending on your use case you should also consider to use different tokenizers and filters while indexing and querying. A good way to analyze what Solr is doing with the data while indexing and querying is to use the Analysis Tool https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen

Comment: Sorry. Actually, I have updated my question and forgot to change the ngram tokens of whether word. There is any way to sort the suggestion w.r.t query using edit distance.